# Where to user clear_block in forms

Tags: oracleforms

I am working on forms 9i. I want to clear the block after inserting record(s). I am writing clear_block(NO_VALIDATE) in post-insert trigger. But it is showing Restricted procedure error. How to use it or is there any other way to clear the form.

Comment: Why do you need to clear the block? Forms have no specific trigger for that case, which would enable restricted procedures. You can override KEY-COMMIT trigger and call clear_block after commit_form, but this doeas not cover other situations leading to commit. Is it really neccessary to clear the block?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new push button or use an existing push button in which suppose commit_form; code is written to save the changes, after that line add the following code in when-button-pressed trigger:
Example

```
Begin
   Commit_Form;
   Go_block('yourblock');
   Clear_Block(no_validate);
End;
```